# how can i pause the previous sound clip on click on other sound clip?

Tags: android, media-player

in my code I have 2 sounds. I would like to know how do i pause the sounds if click on other sounds.
I am very new to android programming,and I really appreciate your help.

{

```
         final MediaPlayer mp2 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.okay);
            Button zero = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.button4);
            zero.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    mp2.start();


                }
            });
          }

        {

            final MediaPlayer mp1 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.mine);

            Button zero = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.button40);
            zero.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                     mp1.start();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking at playing short sounds (like sound effects) I would recommend using a `SoundPool`. You can read more about them [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html). I think it's more suited to what you're trying to do.

Otherwise your solution above could work like this:

```
final MediaPlayer mp2 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.okay);
final MediaPlayer mp1 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.mine);

Button zero = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.button4);
zero.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mp2.start();
        mp1.pause();
    }
});

Button anotherButton = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.button_another);
anotherButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mp1.start();
        mp2.pause();
    }
});
```

The buttons will play different sounds.

Comment: Hello Ken, i did try it, but I don't know why the first sound still works when i click on the second sound to play. So they works together at the same time :'(...
i will learn more about soundpool.
Thank you very much Ken Wolf :)